# csv export data with utf-8 encoding is garbled php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv, utf-8

So I have this page that converts the database into csv.

Database is set to utf8, also when converting is set to utf8.

problem is after opening the csv file in excel, data is garbled. It looks like this:

```
KN01001     | 荳陦帙,admin@listmaster.com"  | List Master          |                |
KN01002     | 譌ｭ譚ｾ                        | information@e877.jp  |   Info Master  |
```

but when I try to drag-open the file into notepad, data is alright, it shows:

```
"KN01001","荳陦帙","admin@listmaster.com","List Master"
"KN01002","譌ｭ譚ｾ蝣","information@e877.jp","Info Master"
```

How can I make it look alright in excel?

**UPDATE:**

I tried adding PHPExcel as suggested, still gives me same garbled output.

I included my code here, maybe someone could help edit the codes.

**Controller:**

```
public function bg_convcsv($sendTo, $searchName, $searchAdd, $prefKey, $searchKey, $withEmail, $withTel, $withFax) {

        $sendTo = rawurldecode($sendTo);

        $headerArray = array("foreign key", "prefecture_id", "industry_id", "offset", "name", "email", "tel", "fax", "address", "url", "flexible_1", "flexible_2", "flexible_3", "flexible_4", "flexible_5", "sequence", "del_flg", "create_date", "create_user", "update_date", "update_user", "site_name");

        // Header
        $header = str_replace(",", "", $headerArray);

        $datas = implode(',', $header) . "\r\n";

        // Body
        $limit = 50000;
        $start = 0;
        do {
            $list = $this->user_model->get_users($searchName, $searchAdd, $prefKey, $searchKey, $withEmail, $withTel, $withFax, $limit, $start);
            foreach($list as $body)
            {
                $email = //some codes to clean email
                $url = // some codes to clean url
                $datas .= '"' .$body["id"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["prefecture_id"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["industry_id"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["offset"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["name"].'"'.",".'"' .$email .'"'. ",".'"' .$body["tel"].'"'. ",".'"' .$body["fax"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["address"].'"'.",".'"' .$url.'"'.",".'"' .$body["flexible_1"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["flexible_2"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["flexible_3"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["flexible_4"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["flexible_5"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["sequence"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["del_flg"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["create_date"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["create_user"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["update_date"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["update_user"].'"'.",".'"' .$body["site_name"].'"'."\r\n";

            }

            $start += $limit;
        }while(count($list) > 0);

        $fileName = "listmaster_".date('YmdHis').".csv";
        $csv_handler = fopen ('/var/www/citest/csv/'.$fileName,'w');
        fwrite ($csv_handler,$datas);
        fclose ($csv_handler);
}

public function download() {

            log_message('debug', 'starting download.');
            $file = $_GET['file'];
            $filePath = '/var/www/citest/csv/'.$file;

            if(!$file){ // file does not exist
                die('file not found');
            } else {
                header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
                header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Expires: 0");
                header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");

                // read the file from disk
                log_message('debug', 'reading file.');
                readfile($filePath);
                log_message('debug', 'reading file done');
            }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here's How I did it using PHPExcel

```
require_once('/var/www/citest/application/third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('/var/www/citest/application/third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

...
...

public function bg_convcsv($sendTo, $searchName, $searchAdd, $prefKey, $searchKey, $withEmail, $withTel, $withFax) {

        $sendTo = rawurldecode($sendTo);

        //Create a new Object
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        // Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 

        $headerArray = array("foreign key", "prefecture_id", "industry_id", "offset", "name", "email", "tel", "fax", "address", "url", "flexible_1", "flexible_2", "flexible_3", "flexible_4", "flexible_5", "sequence", "del_flg", "create_date", "create_user", "update_date", "update_user", "site_name");

        // Header
        $rowNumberH = 1; //set in which row title is to be printed
        $colH = 'A'; //set in which column title is to be printed

        foreach($headerArray as $h){ 
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colH.$rowNumberH,$h);
            $colH++;    
        }

        // Body
        $limit = 50000;
        $start = 0;
        do {
            $list = $this->user_model->get_users($searchName, $searchAdd, $prefKey, $searchKey, $withEmail, $withTel, $withFax, $limit, $start);
            $rowCount = 2; // set the starting row from which the data should be printed
            log_message('debug', "Query: offset:{$start} limit:{$limit} done");
            foreach($list as $body)
            {
                //$email =

                //$url =

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $body['id']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $body['prefecture_id']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $body['industry_id']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $body['offset']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $body['name']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount, $email);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount, $body['tel']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $body['fax']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $body['address']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount, $url);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $body['flexible_1']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $body['flexible_2']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$rowCount, $body['flexible_3']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N'.$rowCount, $body['flexible_4']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O'.$rowCount, $body['flexible_5']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P'.$rowCount, $body['sequence']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q'.$rowCount, $body['del_flg']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('R'.$rowCount, $body['create_date']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S'.$rowCount, $body['create_user']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('T'.$rowCount, $body['update_date']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('U'.$rowCount, $body['update_user']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('V'.$rowCount, $body['site_name']);
                $rowCount++; 

            }

            $start += $limit;
        }while(count($list) > 0);

        $fileName = "listmaster_".date('YmdHis').".csv";

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($fileName);

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
        $objWriter->setDelimiter(',');
        $objWriter->save('/var/www/citest/csv/' . $fileName);

}
```

Comment: try use phpexcel to make sure the format is correct for excel

Comment: Try to open with UTF-8 charset, it's working for me: https://imgur.com/a/465nb

Comment: If you are dealing with Chinese, you should use `utf8mb4` in MySQL instead of `utf8`.

Comment: Did you try using `Excel2007` flag instead of `CSV` in the `createWriter()` call?

Answer (score 0):

As @luhuiya mentioned, you can use phpexcel in order to have the correct format.

Supposed you already installed phpexcel with [composer](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel).

Here is a working example:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
You query your data into an array here
$data = ...
*/

$data = [
    [ 'KN01001', '荳陦帙', 'admin@listmaster.com', 'List Master', '' ],
    [ 'KN01002', '譌ｭ譚ｾ', 'information@e877.jp', 'Info Master', '' ],
];

$phpXls = new PHPExcel();

// Fill worksheet from values in array
$phpXls->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data, null, 'A1');

// Work on PHPExcel object, set worksheet metadata
// Change the ... parts according to your needs
$phpXls->getProperties()->setCreator("...")
    ->setLastModifiedBy("...")
    ->setTitle("...")
    ->setSubject("...")
    ->setDescription("...")
    ->setKeywords("...");

$phpXls->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('...');

// I saw in your examlpe data, that you can have long strings in some columns
// Therefore You can widen the excel columns in order to be readable at full length.
// Get Excel column range and dynamically resize columns
$highestColumn = $phpXls->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
foreach (range(0, $highestColumnIndex) as $columnIndex) {
    $phpXls->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensionByColumn($columnIndex)->setAutoSize(true);
}

 // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$phpXls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Save Excel 2007 file
$xlsWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpXls, 'Excel2007');

$xlsWriter->save('your_data.xlsx');
```